# Using UC3844 and TL431 to compensate a forward converter

Tags: buck, control-system, spice, compensation, tl431

I am designing a forward converter capable of providing 5A at 30V at the output. For the compensation part, I am thinking to use UC3844 in combination with TL431 to achieve peak current mode control.

I read the datasheet of UC3844 on how to use it, but I cannot understand how to use the VFB and COMP pin for my purpose. This is the schematic that I have currently:

[image]

Before I actually start designing the compensation loop, I need to get the Control-to-Output bode plot first but I don't know to do it with UC3844 in the picture.

Does plotting the bode plot as shown below the same as plotting it with UC3844? Or I can reframe this question as does UC3844 add any kind of gain to the loop without any compensation network in the picture?

[image]

This is the result that I got btw with this approach:

[image]

Comment: Viewed  this first ? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3844.pdf?ts=1636008657962 figure 25   ... It is ~ complete except output voltage lower (only quasi need output transformer change).

Comment: It took me some time to understand the complete datasheet but yeah now my doubts have been cleared.